# Nicescroll in jQuery Mobile popups

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup, nicescroll

I have been using the excellent [NiceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) plugin in my jQuery Mobile application.  The one issue I have run into is when I use NiceScroll in a popup.  When the user hits the Esc key to dismiss the popup the scrollbar remains behind.  "Not a problem" I thought - I'll just record the scrollbar object and call its .remove() method from the popupafterclose event for the popup.  However, there is an issue - the popupafterclose event does not get triggered for so long as the scrollbar is present (even after the actual popup has disappeared).  The jQM docs state

*This event is triggered when the popup has completely disappeared from the screen, meaning that all associated animations have completed.*

So what I am seeing implies that the orphaned scrollbar that hangs around is equivalent to "all associated animations" **not being** complete.

As a stop gap solution I am keeping track of created Nicescrolls in an array, checking the Esc key at document level and calling remove() on the last element of that array.  This works but feels rather hackish.  I would be much obliged to anyone who might be able to suggest a better way.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can see the generated code? perhaps you can change the DOM parent of the scroll from body to the popup?

Comment: Yes, I will create the fiddle.  The scroll is absolutely positioned so changes there would require the popup body to be relatively positioned at the very least. I toyed with the idea of doing this but balked at the prospect of digressing into an entirely different project at the expense of my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you a working example that don't suffer from this problem.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/N28Vg/83/

#### HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Index page</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop">Basic Popup</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
            <div class="header" data-role="header">
                <h1>Products</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="content" data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>                
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>                
                </ul>                
            </div>
            <div class="footer" data-role="footer">
                <a class="close" href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>                
    </div>

    <div data-theme="b" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>    
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

Use this:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(".content").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#00F"});
});
```

or this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $(".content").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#00F"});
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gajotres.  I have tried to capture the essence of what you have done [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zca2G/). Amongst other things I wanted to check that the popupafteropen/close events fire correctly. I am not sure why you need the div.iscroll CSS rules. Please let me know if you see any issues with my simplified version of your solution. In essence I think what you have done is moved the scrollbar to a div **inside** the popup?

Comment: Forget that specific CSS rule, it was a left over. I was also testing iScrollView inside a popup.

Comment: Thanks @Gajtores.  I have accepted your answer - certainly a whole lot better than the hack I had coded in.  I'd be much obliged if you could comment on my simplified version of your fiddle - do you see any issues there?

Comment: Give me some time and I will send you a comment.